# trap and activators in scintillation materials

Tags: photons

I'm not getting my head around the difference between traps and activators in [scintillators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scintillation_(physics)).
What do they do? As far as I understood, activators add new levels below the conduction band (within the band gap). What are traps then?

P.S.: The tag "luminescence/scintillation" should really exist :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traps are centers in the crystal (often impurities) with energy levels in the bandgap. They can catch a charge carrier (electron or hole) permanently. This prevents these charge carriers to contribute to the wanted scintillation. On the other hand, activators are impurities in scintillator crystals (e.g, thallium in NaJ) that contribute to the efficiency of light emission.

Comment: Thanks a lot! When traps and activators are impurites: What separates them?

Comment: @Ben - Traps are just (chemically) different impurities (or defects) than activators  in the crystal