# Laser Physics: Question Concerning SPAD

Tags: photons, semiconductor-physics, laser

In a Laser Physics lecture, we had had the following Figure for a SPAD (a single photon APD):

The reasons for which the detection efficiency, which is plotted on the y-axis, goes down as a function of the wavelengths for $\lambda \lesssim 600$ nm is that Si$_{3}$N$_{4}$ is used to prevent the oxidation of Si, at least according to our Prof., while for larger wavelengths, the band of gap couldn't be bridged anymore.

**Question**: Couldn't it be that Silicon also oxidates for larger wavelengths? But why, then, isn't an anti-oxidation material used for these ranges of the wavelengths?

[image]

Comment: I find the last paragraph quite confusing. Do you assume the detected light causes the silicon to oxidize if it's not protected?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know, but I don't think so. But why do we get an oxidation for smaller wavelengths and not anymore for $\lambda \gtrsim 580$ nm?

Comment: Where do you have that information from? The blue annotation in the diagram just says that the protective silicon nitride layer absorbs part of the shorter wavelengths, so that less light hits the silicon chip and triggers an avalanche.

Comment: And that's okay that our protective silicon nitride layer doesn't absorb parts of the larger wavelengths?

Comment: Yes, that's good. Because it's supposed to protect the silicon from oxygen, not to block the light that should be detected.

Comment: Ah okay. But why don't we want to detect light at smaller wavelengths? And would the oxygen lead to a fake rate of the photons? That I don't understand either yet..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119169/discussion-between-a-p-and-mathisfun).

Answer (score 0):

When an [APD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avalanche_photodiode) is designed one has to make some material choices depending on which wavelength the detector should be optimized for. In the example graph you show the photons are detected in Silicon, which if undoped, has a bandgap of [1.14 eV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Band_gap#List_of_band_gaps:~:text=IV%09Silicon%09Si%091.14%09%5B10%5D). This corresponds to a wavelength of 1088 nm. Photons with lower energy can't excite an electron into the conduction band and therefore not trigger the avanlanche ("Unüberbrückbarkeit der Bandlücke"). Due to the [indirect bandgap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_and_indirect_band_gaps#Formula_for_absorption) of silicon even higher energy photons aren't guaranteed to excite an electron.

To prevent chemical degradation of the silicon it is coated by a passivation layer – in your example Si<sub>3</sub>N<sub>4</sub>. Unfortunately this material can also absorb photons ("Absorption der Passivierungsschicht aus Si<sub>3</sub>N<sub>4</sub>") and therefore prevent them from being detected, but it has a much larger bandgap of [5 eV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Band_gap#List_of_band_gaps:~:text=IV%E2%80%93V%09Silicon%20nitride%09Si3N4%095). This corresponds to a wavelength of 248 nm, but apparently the APD efficiency drops already for lower frequency photons. This is because the material has many [defects, which have an energy between the valence and the conduction band](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/385788/169454). They can absorb photons with lower energy as well.